# Why is one steak soft and 1 rock hard

Tags: steak

I bought 2 fillet steaks from supermarket and stored them in the fridge. Anyone know why one is soft and the other rock hard right after I remove from packaging and are they both ok to eat? They were both in the same packaging.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe not cut from the same beef or the same section of the filet ?

Comment: One partially froze and protected the other one from partially freezing?

Comment: Pictures would help for this sort of thing (to identify if they’re from different places, or if they have different fat distribution). But as it’s a week later, I suspect you’ve already eaten them by now